# How to solve this TypeError Exception in Pylibmodbus?

Tags: python, modbus

I am trying to create this ModbusRtu object however when I try to insert some parameters, it seems to raise an error. Even when I just try to run it with its original parameters as dictated by the author, the same error rises. I currently have all of the required packages installed.

libffi-dev - 3.2.1-4
libmodbus - 3.1.4-2
libmodbus-dev - 3.1.4-2
python-dev - 2.7.15~rc1-1
cffi - 2.19

I really confused why it should not work since even the author-defined parameters seem to create the same error as well.

I already tried following its message by converting the parameters into bytes, or list, or tuple, but it only raises another exception

````
``` Python Code 1 (before my solution)
self.master = ModbusRtu(device='/dev/ttyACM0', 
                        baud=9600, data_bit=8, 
                        parity='N', stop_bit=1)

``` Python Code 2 (after my solution)
self.master = ModbusRtu(device=bytes('/dev/ttyACM0', 'ascii), 
                        baud=9600, data_bit=8, 
                        parity=bytes('N', 'ascii), stop_bit=1)


``` Simpler Python Code 1
from pylibmodbus import ModbusRtu

def main():
    client = ModbusRtu()
    # i can't instantiate the ModbusRtu class
    print(client)
    # i should have at least the id of the instantiated class
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
````

It is supposedly create the object, however I only got this message:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pylibmodbus/modbus_rtu.py", line 11, in **init**
    self.ctx = C.modbus_new_rtu(device, baud, parity, data_bit, 
                                stop_bit)
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str

When I try converting the string parameters into bytes I got this message:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pylibmodbus/modbus_core.py", line 60, in _run
    raise Exception(ffi.string(C.modbus_strerror(ffi.errno)))
Exception: b'No such file or directory'

Comment: The instantiation should be: self.master = ModbusRtu(device='/dev/ttyACM0', baud=9600, data_bit=8, parity='N', stop_bit=1), are you sure you're using the correct repository?

Comment: I am using this one https://github.com/stephane/pylibmodbus or https://pypi.org/project/pylibmodbus/, thru pypi or pip install. Meanwhile the required packages were installed thru Ubuntu software app while cffi thru pypi as well.

Comment: OK, those are fine. But, why are you doing the parity=bytes'N'? Maybe it was just a typo? Anyway, I think the first thing to do is check is if your libmodbus is working. You can clone libmodbus from here https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus go to the tests folder and compile and run "unit_test_client.c" and "unit_test_server.c"? You should be able to do it with-->$ gcc -o unit_test_client -I/usr/include/modbus unit_test_client.c -lmodbus

Comment: Once you have compiled those you can run both (on different terminals) and they should be able to run a series of tests talking to each other

Comment: I did it and got a success message, although I used the random-test-client and random-test-server instead. I get error messages when I am trying to compile unit-test-client and unit-test-server.

Comment: OK, great, now you know libmodbus is working, if you can edit your question to show a usable part of your code I can test it, what you posted should work as it is...

Comment: I also did the pylibmodbus test.py, and gave me an OK message.

Comment: Then you're good to go, your setup is fine. There must be something wrong with your code somewhere else...

Comment: I edited the code already however I am sure if this is what are you referring about. But the main problem that I am facing is that I can't even instantiate the ModbusRtu class moreover receive data from the Arduino Mega simulated slave and sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me with Python 2.x:

```
from pylibmodbus import ModbusRtu

client=ModbusRtu(device="/dev/ttyACM0", baud=19200, parity="N", data_bit=8, stop_bit=1)

client.connect()
SERVER_ID=0

client.set_slave(SERVER_ID)

client.write_registers(0, [0]*10)

result=(client.read_registers(0, 10))
print result

client.close()
```

For Python 3.x you have to **encode the text**, I think that was your problem:

from pylibmodbus import ModbusRtu

```
client=ModbusRtu(device="/dev/ttyACM0".encode("ascii"), baud=19200, parity="N".encode("ascii"), data_bit=8, stop_bit=1)

client.connect()
SERVER_ID=0

client.set_slave(SERVER_ID)

client.write_registers(0, [0]*10)

result=(client.read_registers(0, 10))
print(result)

client.close()
```

Comment: Could this mean that the library only works with Python 2.x? What I am using right now is Python 3.7. The author tells that it is compatible with Python 3 as well.

Comment: That made my brain just click! I was dealing with this issue just last week but I had forgotten about it. I edited my answer with a solution for Python 3.x

Comment: I also did the .encode('ascii') however I only just did it for the parity. Thanks!